# How do I safely add a missing partition to an existing RAID-1 setup?

Tags: linux, centos, raid, raid1

My server had RAID-1 setup and a few days ago one drive failed. I replaced it and added it back to the array. The problem is that the 3TB drive had 2 partitions:

```
root@s01 [~]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_server01-LogVol01
                      2.7T  419G  2.2T  17% /
tmpfs                 7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/md0              477M  149M  303M  33% /boot
/dev/md2               32G  6.5G   24G  22% /mysql
/usr/tmpDSK           4.0G  223M  3.6G   6% /tmp
root@s01 [~]#
```

So basically 2.7TB for `/`, 7.8GB for `tmpfs` and 477MB for `boot`.

So both `md0` and `md1` were on the same drive. The failed drive was then re-added with `mdadm --manage /dev/md1 --add /dev/sdc2`

The problem now as you can see is that `md1` was synced up but `md0` was left out:

```
root@s01 [~]# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] 
md0 : active raid1 sdd1[1]
      511988 blocks super 1.0 [2/1] [_U]

md2 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdb1[1]
      33558657 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md1 : active raid1 sdc1[2] sdd2[1]
      2929751932 blocks super 1.1 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 6/22 pages [24KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
root@s01 [~]#
```

Is there any way to safely re-add `md0` without re-formatting everything?

`md0` now looks like:

```
root@s01 [~]# mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.0
  Creation Time : Sat Jul  7 18:23:23 2012
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 511988 (499.99 MiB 524.28 MB)
  Used Dev Size : 511988 (499.99 MiB 524.28 MB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 1
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Thu Jul  7 00:59:54 2016
          State : clean, degraded 
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 1
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           Name : server01.domain.com:0
           UUID : 2ca3a4dc:db3ef0ca:b3d37d49:b43e826f
         Events : 726

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       0        0        0      removed
       1       8       49        1      active sync   /dev/sdd1
root@s01 [~]#
```

and `md1` looks like:

```
root@s01 [~]# mdadm --detail /dev/md1
/dev/md1:
        Version : 1.1
  Creation Time : Sat Jul  7 18:23:24 2012
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 2929751932 (2794.03 GiB 3000.07 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 2929751932 (2794.03 GiB 3000.07 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

  Intent Bitmap : Internal

    Update Time : Thu Jul  7 20:33:31 2016
          State : active 
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           Name : server01.domain.com:1
           UUID : 58600fc5:5348d92c:a7d25465:20d42940
         Events : 2359606

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       2       8       33        0      active sync   /dev/sdc1
       1       8       50        1      active sync   /dev/sdd2
root@s01 [~]#
```

Answer (score 5):

> So both md0 and md1 were on the same drive. The failed drive was then
>   re-added with mdadm --manage /dev/md1 --add /dev/sdc2
>
> The problem now as you can see is that md1 was synced up but md0 was
>   left out:

This is because you readded missing drive only to `/dev/md1`, you need to do the same with `/dev/md0`, like
`mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdcX`

`sdcX` - you need to now what partition to use, we cannot know that.

> Is there any way to safely re-add md0 without re-formatting everything?

You can use `parted`, and find out what is where and what partition is not used. `Mdadm` is quite safe for that, it won't allow you to add device currently in use.

I can bet that you didn't create 2nd partition on that new drive. `Mdadm` allowed you to readd partition with diffrent size (bigger in your case). You should create same partition layout as on `/dev/sdd`. Parted will help you with that as well. You can check `/dev/sdd` layout like this: `parted /dev/sdd unit MiB print`, then compare it with `/dev/sdc`.

Make sure that you align partitions correctly, `parted` will help you with that too, after you create first partition on the new disk, you **should** notice that it start from 2048 sector, 1st MiB. Misalignment in general is bad for disk's performance.

You'll also need, before making partitions:

`mdadm --manage /dev/mdX --fail /dev/sdX` - to mark disk as failed (non-destructive)

`mdadm --manage /dev/mdX --remove /dev/sdX` - to remove disk from array (non-destructive)

Partition the disk accordingly (destructive to some point) and readd it again (non-destructive, to the array of course not for added disk/parition).

Comment: initramfs probably also needs to be updated, if he expects his RAID to start up at next boot